# Motion in a Paul trap: $2n^{\text{th}}$ harmonic with larger amplitude than $n$th harmonic

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, classical-electrodynamics

Using a [Paul trap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_ion_trap), we captured the motion of a light charged particle (based on a rotating potential applied by AC current). Our rotational frequency was 50 Hz, and so when we used the [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) on the data, we were expecting this frequency to have largest amplitude. However, the double frequency, 100 Hz, had as much as twice the amplitude that the 50 Hz had. How can one explain such an observation?

Comment: Maybe a solution, looking at equation $(3)$ of [Paul trap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_ion_trap), is to use a ansatz $u^i = A^i + B^i \cos \Omega t + C^i \cos 2 \Omega t$, then, solving the equation (neglecting terms in $\cos 3 \Omega t$), would give a relation between $B^i$ and $C^i$

Comment: I don't have much experience with experiment, so forgive me if I'm being naive. When you sat "data" do you mean data bout the particle's motion?

And should the particle's motion not depend on how many pairs of "poles" you have in a circle?

Comment: Is it single ion? What kind of Paul trap are you using? How does the potential rotate?

Answer (score 1):

According to your Wikipedia link, there is a scheme showing two states in a single AC cycle.  So the particle and the cloud is pulled (or repelled) from orthogonal plates *twice* for each cycle.  I imagine your motion detector is somewhere between the plates.  Since the particle movement is from a sinusoidal force, you will see the particle move forming a "L" where each vertex and end of the L is where the particle changes direction.  So if you had really trapped the particle in an "I", you would have a 50 Hz back and forth movement.  But since you have a "L", you have two orthogonal movements in a single cycle, or 100Hz movements from the detector's perspective.